# Does the Xresources configuration file affect Wayland?

Tags: x11, fonts, wayland, x-resources

I'm trying to get more Ubuntu-like font-rendering on Fedora 24 with Wayland and I did add `Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault` to `/etc/X11/Xresources` but I don't see much difference. Is there a different way to do this in Wayland? Is it possible?

Comment: Welp, I'm not answering because I'm still not completely sure, but these links allowed me to enable `lcddefaut` and possibly load .Xresources into wayland: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/83818/activating-lcddefault-on-wayland-possible/ and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1225384

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the .Xresources file doesn't affect Wayland's display. If you want it to work, use:

```
xrdb -load ~/.Xresources
```

to load the configuration.